# QList of templated structures

Tags: c++, qt, templates, struct, qlist

Consider the following two structures:

```
template <typename T> struct duplet{
  QString str;
  T value;
}

struct MyObject{
QList<struct duplet> myList;
}
```

The compiler throws the following error:

error C3203: 'Duplet' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type

Is it syntax error that I am stumbling upon or a an illegal declaration ??

Thanks,
de costo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its simply that duplet, as a template, must be fully specified in order to serve as a template argument?  The compiler can't create the mylist instance because it doesn't know what type it is.  'duplet' is not a (complete) type; 'duplet< T > for some type T' is.

```
struct MyObject {
QList<struct duplet<int> > myList;
```

and

```
template <typename T>
struct MyObject {
QList<struct duplet<T> > myList;
```

compile just fine for me.